# Creating a dictionary of dataframes based on another dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary to hold `DataFrames A` which are indexed with a `month-year` key. Now, I want to create another dictionary of `DataFrames B` (with the `cost-item` key) which keeps a recod of each column over time (getting the columns from `A`).

Here is an example:

```
A[0114]=
  title  cost1   cost2
0 FL     100     200
1 GA     300     400

A[0214]=
  title  cost1   cost2
0 FL     150     250
1 GA     100     300

B[cost1]=
  title  0114   0214
0 FL     100    150
1 GA     300    100

B[cost2]=
  title  0114   0214
0 FL     200    250
1 GA     400    300
```

Here is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
cost_item=['cost1', 'cost2']
month_year_list=['0114', '0214']
for item in cost_item:
    B[item] = {}
    B[item]['title']= pd.Series(A['0114']['title'], index=A['0114'].index)
    for month_year in month_year_list:
        B[item][month_year]=pd.Series(A[month_year][item], index=A['0114'].index)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple using a Panel

```
for key in A:
    A[key].index = A[key].pop('title')
panel = pd.Panel(A)
B = panel.swapaxes(0,2)
```

Technically B will also be a Panel and title will be the major axis, but you could do

```
B = {item: B[item] for item in B}
for key in B:
    B[key]['title'] = B.index
```

if you really want a dictionary with the original structure. A Panel seems more appropriate though, unless you have many elements in title that aren't common across the dataframes in A.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, I tried to implement your code using `Panel`, but I get `KeyError: 'title'`.